# Thread-safe update TextBox from another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a form called 'Home' and a class called 'Server', which is threaded.  Home has a TextBox that I'd like to append as things happen in Server.  What is easiest thread safe way to append the text box that's not in the same class?  I see a lot of talk on this subject but nothing seems to answer my question.  The other solutions also contain a lot of code for something that seems simple.

I start my thread form Home like so:

```
public void StartThread()
{
    Server s = new Server();
    Thread t = new Thread(s.DoWork);
    t.Start();
}

class Server
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            StartServer();
        }
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }

    private volatile bool _shouldStop;

    internal void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
        // Server Stuff
        // Something happens here and I want to append a string to the text box in Home.
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Exception, append text box with some other string.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why in the world are you doing a busy wait on the thread for it to finish?  That defeats the whole purpose of starting another thread.

Comment: There are some other conditions for the wait.  Just didn't snip it out with the rest.

Comment: It still shouldn't be there.  It shouldn't be waiting at all.

Comment: I have my reasons.  What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: I'm just telling you that it's a very bad idea, and almost certainly going to be causing you problems.  Whatever it is you're trying to do, you should be doing it asynchronously, and not waiting on the thread to finish.  And if you *really* must wait (which isn't going to end up being the case) then at the very least you shouldn't be doing a busy wait on the thread.

Comment: @BobbyTurkalino as Servy pointed out it feels like you explicitly want to prevent updates of UI while other thread is running (AKA "why my UI is Frozen when I Sleep on UI thread"), which is somewhat fine as long as it is your intention (may make Windows unhappy and mark your window "unresponsive" so) ...Mainly it feels strange sample for "update UI" question...

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It's for testing and not permanent.  I just used it as a break point so I could see some stuff before it went in to the next part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Have the form create a `Progress<string>` instace,
2. Attach a handler to the progress changed event that updates the UI appropriately.
3. Have the worker accept an `IProgress<string>` instance that it reports progress to.

The `Progress` class will handle marshaling the code to the UI thread.

This ensures proper separation of UI from non-UI code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean (Preforming cross threaded operations I assume?) but...

```
textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { textBox1.AppendText("Hi"); }));
```

This would be to append some text to your textbox safely, you would just have to add the if statement and such.